# jquery to find label element with text equal to foobar

Tags: jquery

Given:

```
  <div>
    <label>
      Age
    </label>
  </div>
```

How do I find the element that is a label with content equal to "Age" with jQuery

Comment: Not sure it matters what I've tried . 

jQuery("label").has('age'); 

for example doesn't work

Comment: better leave the questions like this to google to prevent yourself from getting banned, no offense "I'm banned"

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... 
The answer is:

```
jQuery("label:contains('Age')");
```